# 100,000+ Annotations with MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift2, mkpointannotation

I'm writing a simple iOS App to map about 130,000 items.

I took the raw data file and massaged each line to look like:

```
array.append(class(latitude:46.222813, longitude:6.138866))
```

But when I try to copy 130,000 lines or even 25,000 at a time, Xcode just hangs.

Now, I'm happy to copy/paste 1000 at a time, but was wondering if I should be dealing with a sqlite database? Or just a .CSV text file in my project...

Thoughts? Suggestions? Admonitions? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the data in a file or database. Then you have code that loads the file/data and iterates over each entry.

Now your code is now about a dozen lines of code instead of 130,000 and the coordinates are not hardcoded in your app.

Comment: Thanks!! Are you thinking a CSV file, a sql database, or something else?

I haven't learned how to deal with files in my app, but that was going to be my first Google search this morning.

Comment: I'd use a database file. This way the data is stored in a much more usable format (especially for so much data) and your app will have a lot more flexibility if you just want to query some of the data and you don't need the whole file in memory at once.

Comment: quick follow-up question, as it's late and i can't seem to find the answer quickly.....

when you say "database file" do you mean Core Data? Or can I create a sqlite file on my Mac and then drag-drop it into my Xcode project and interact with it there with code?

Comment: Personally I'd use SQLite because I don't mind working at that level. Core Data is probably huge overkill to simply read data from a static database table.

Comment: So, I ended up using a tab-delimited file. It takes a while to load, so I might try to find a way to speed it up using another data storage option.